# trello's Graphical User Interface

Tags: frontend, trello

Anybody here knows which technology or framework or whatever is being used to present that nice GUI on Trello website ?
I'm a little bit outdated about front-end technologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the front-end, Trello predominately uses jQuery and Backbone.js. All of the modals, menu, and dialog windows are custom. All of the CSS is custom. Trello uses and [icon font](http://blog.fogcreek.com/trello-uses-an-icon-font-and-so-can-you/) for icons.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery on the site.  Are you seeing some somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very nice write up of the Trello tech stack from Fog Creek (the creators): 
[The Trello Tech Stack](http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/)

In a nutshell *(if you're too busy to read the article)* they use:

### Client

- Backbone (for client-side MVC)
- HTML5 (for pushState)
- Mustache (for templating)

### Server

- node.js
- HAProxy
- Redis
- MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Looking in a decade later - after looking at some of the resources loaded on a Trello `board` page, it looks like the following core tech:

- React
- TypeScript
- Redux

Also see bootstrap being listed but not sure where it's being used.